# how to plot data extracted from list of list?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list contain data like this example

`data=[[january-b1,0.25,0.33],[february-b1,0.254,0.9],...,[august-b1,0.1,0.13],[january-b2,0.25,0.33],[february-b2,0.254,0.9],...,[august-b3,0.1,0.13]....]`

each months have 10 band b1..b10 and 2 values . I want to plot variation of each band as a function of months .each band have 2 figures :the variation of the first value and the second value.

Comment: As a good approach for future questions consider to show also some approach you may have tried first before, which didn't solve your problem as expected, and show your results.

Comment: yes i tried but i didn't get any good results thats why i posted my question here.

Comment: Still if you get bad resuts it's better seen in this site if you add that code in your question and the error code or bad results you get. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pandas` package and then plot with `matplotlib` as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data=[["january-b1",0.25,0.33],["february-b1",0.254,0.9],["august-b1",0.1,0.13],["january-b2",0.25,0.33],["february-b2",0.254,0.9],["august-b3",0.1,0.13]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Month-band","first value","second value"])
df.set_index(["Month-band"],inplace=True,drop=True)
df.plot()
plt.show()
```

This would result in following graph:
[image]

### Python versions

Above code was tested under `Python 3.7.6`and `Pandas 0.24.2`. After OP's comment I tested with `Python 2.7.16` and `Pandas 0.23.4` and the xticklabels where not populated as expected.

Under `Python 2.7` it seems you should replace a line (which just saves the plot to a variable) and add a new line setting the xticklabels:

```
ax = df.plot()
ax.set_xticklabels(df.index)
```

### Plotting only one column

If you want to plot only one of the values you can do the following:

```
df["first value"].plot()
```

Comment: thanks sir this solution helped me but i didn't get the horizontal axis (months are not written bellow) and i really need to see the variation  like it shown in ur graph .

Comment: Did you try same code as the example I presented? The dataframe needs to have set the month names as the index using the `set_index` function. You should include that code line for this.

Comment: yeah even the same example with the same data that you used show no months.

Comment: @oussamabousselmi, I think that's related with Python version. I tried with Python 3.7. With Python 2.7 I see the xlabels are not shown the same way. Let me see a workaround.

Comment: can i plot each band in separate figure?

Comment: Please see updated answer for xlabel issue you have and how to plot each value in separate figures.

Answer (score 3):

This could be a first aproximation

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#plt.clf()
plt.ylabel('ylabel')
plt.xlabel('xlabel')
plt.title("My plot")

data=[["january-b1",0.25,0.33],["february-b1",0.254,0.9],["august-b1",0.1,0.13]]
labels,l_v1,l_v2 = [],[],[]
for l,v1,v2 in data:
    labels.append(l)
    l_v1.append(v1)
    l_v2.append(v2)
plt.plot(range(len(labels)), l_v1,linestyle='--', marker='o', color='blue')
plt.plot(range(len(labels)), l_v2, linestyle='--', marker='o', color='red')
plt.xticks(range(len(labels)),labels)
#plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Another possible solution (each line represents a month).
There are 2 lines by month, the color of the lines of the variables of the same month is similar.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#plt.clf()
plt.ylabel('ylabel')
plt.xlabel('xlabel')
plt.title("My plot")
colors = [
    "red", "orange", "blue", "purple", "yellow", "olive", "aqua",
    "red", "orange", "blue", "purple", "yellow", "olive"
]
data = [["january-b1", 0.25, 0.33], ["january-b2", 0.23, 0.33],["january-b3", 0.25, 0.33],
        ["february-b1", 0.254, 0.9],["february-b2", 0.274, 0.79],["february-b3", 0.254, 0.94],
        ["august-b1", 0.12, 0.13],["august-b2", 0.1, 0.13],["august-b3", 0.0, 0.23]]


variables_dict_1 = {}
variables_dict_2 = {}
for l,v1,v2 in data:
    label = l.split("-")[0]
    pos = l.split("-")[1].split("b")[-1]
    print(pos)
    pos = int(pos)-1

    aux = variables_dict_1.get(label,[0]*3) #change * 13 in your data
    aux[pos] = v1
    variables_dict_1[label] = aux

    aux = variables_dict_2.get(label, [0] * 3)  #change * 13 in your data
    aux[pos] = v2
    variables_dict_2[label] = aux

colors = [("red","salmon"),("blue","steelblue"),("orange","goldenrod")]
print(variables_dict_1.keys())
print(variables_dict_1)

for i,l in enumerate(variables_dict_1.keys()):
    plt.plot(range(len(variables_dict_1[l])), variables_dict_1[l],linestyle='--', marker='o', color=colors[i][0])
    plt.plot(range(len(variables_dict_1[l])), variables_dict_2[l], linestyle='--', marker='o', color=colors[i][1])
#plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
plt.show()
```

[image]